# How can i make multiple hiveserver2 in HDP 2.2 and ambari 1.7

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, ambari

I am having 1 hiveserver2 in 30 node cluster now I wan to make 4 hiveserver2 daemon through ambari. How can i make multiple hiveserver2 in HDP 2.2 and ambari 1.7 ?

I know we can start hive server directly and set the properties to auto search but this daemon we cant monitor through ambari.

Answer (score 1):

It's only supported in Ambari 2.0.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-8906